# PHP library to ease creation of processes (fork)

Tags: php, fork

Do you know any library that eases work with processes, signal sending etc? Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
We're doing some data loading from external sources in PHP daemon. We want to split PHP process to have:

- one process for loading per every data source,
- one process for processing data that came from every data source.

Comment: Whats your goal? You should explain it some more.

Comment: I added a comment about usage, thx!

Comment: Maybe the solution is to create many deamon processes with one "owner" that will read queue of jobs that needs to be done. Depending on how many processes will be created by user, that many will be processing jobs in parallel. Maybe usage of http://www.zeromq.org/ will be right solution to do implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check out [Spork](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/spork), it's designed to ease forking and background processing in php.

It's pretty new (announced just 3 days ago), but worth a try.

Comment: Pretty new - 11 years ago :D Hardly any change since, it seems.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [process control](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) library, but it works only on linux.

For `fork` purposes it contains `pcntl_fork` function. [Example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php):

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid == -1) {
     die('could not fork');
} else if ($pid) {
     // we are the parent
     pcntl_wait($status); //Protect against Zombie children
} else {
     // we are the child
}
```

**UPD:** if I correct understand your goals you design your application without forking of processes. You can use two daemons where first daemon will process data source and add it to queue. The second daemon will track the queue and process it.

P.s. As I know php can not fork processes on windows platforms. Also for additional you can use [POSIX function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.posix.php) in php.

Comment: What about Windows possibilities to achieve goals I described? To achieve "multi-threading" "multi-processing"?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I'm looking for existing and proven solution to make jobs in parallel.